# chrome popup window in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extensions development, i want to build an extension which captures the url from the browsers url address bar and the protocol of that url.
If the visiting url protocol is not https then extension must be show a popup which contain some message. I have a following code which is working fine but the problem is that it display a popup message after clicking on extension icon so what i want the popup should be display automatically when user visiting some non https protocol url. The code is below.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color",
  "description": "Change the current page color",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","notifications","webNavigation", "*://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){

    createNotification();

});

});

function createNotification(){
var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your   message",iconUrl: "icon.png"}
chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});
}
```

Comment: actually i don't want to show tool bar popup i just want notification popup

Comment: Well then move the code in a background page script, see also: [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).